# Thymeleaf Spring Boot Webflow not submitting form properly th:each and button

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-webflow

The following works as intended with no issue

phoneLookup

```
<form class="" autocomplete="off" th:object="${user}" method="post" role="form">
        <div class="row" style="margin-top: 20px">
        <div class="input-field col s8 offset-s2">
            <input th:field="*{phoneNo}" id="icon_telephone" type="number" class="validate" style="height: 160px !important; text-align: center; font-size: 100px" data-length="10">
            <label for="icon_telephone" style="font-size: 40px">Telephone</label>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block green darken-1 col s8 offset-s2" name="_eventId_phoneEntered" style="height: 100px; font-size: 33px;">Lookup Phone Number</button>
        </div>
        </form>
```

However, a form with a thymeleaf th:each allows the button to be clicked but it just refreshes the current page

confirmCustomer.html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m9">
        <div th:each="addresses: ${addresses}">
            <form class="" autocomplete="off" th:object="${address}" method="post" role="form">
                <h1 th:text="${addresses.street1}"></h1>
                <h1 th:text="${addresses.apt}"></h1>
                <h1 th:text="${addresses.special}"></h1>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block green darken-1 col s8 offset-s2" name="_eventId_useAddress">Lookup Phone Number</button>
                <input type="hidden" value="${addresses.idaddresses}" name="idaddresses" />
            </form>



        </div>
```

Removing everything and just leaving the form tags and the button allows the page to proceed on to the next part of the flow.

```
<form class="" autocomplete="off" th:object="${address}" method="post" role="form">

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block green darken-1 col s8 offset-s2" name="_eventId_useAddress">Lookup Phone Number</button>
            </form>
```

I've tried changing the button to a link and using Spring from tags all to no avail.

I'm starting to think it has something to do with a value being assigned to the button during th:each. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
 <input type="hidden" value="${addresses.idaddresses}" name="idaddresses" />
```

to

```
 <input type="hidden" th:value="${addresses.idaddresses}" name="idaddresses" />
```

thymeleaf was not passing the value to the controller because it did not have "th:value"

Comment: Could you please add some more information as to how your answer solves the problem in question? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the HTML `action` attribute in your `form` tag.  If this needs to include variables, then you'll want to include `th:action` and follow the examples as set forward in the documentation.

You can also remove `class=""` since it's meaningless.

Comment: I had already looked into that. After doing some more debugging, I realized that

Comment: I had already looked into that. After doing some more debugging, I realized that  <input type="hidden" value="${addresses.idaddresses}" name="idaddresses" />   is causing an issue. After closer inspection I need to change value to th:value....